# pip install error with 'scandir'

Tags: python-2.7, pip

When I use python2 to install jupyter notebook, the terminal breaks down and display `failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-bWqlTC/scandir/`, and the python version is 2.7 in Linux Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please include the entire error stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Download [here](https://pypi.org/project/scandir/#files) and install with file type .whl.